# Jenkins REST API, filter builds based on build number and get result in JSON

Tags: java, json, xml, rest, jenkins

I am trying to fetch the builds in my Java code from a hosted Jenkins server by using the Jenkins REST API (JSON).

I am saving all the builds in my database and I would like to fetch all the builds of a job after the build number up to which the builds are already saved in my database.

I can do this by using the XML API by using XPATH expressions like this:

`https://<JENKINS_HOST>/job/<JOB_NAME>/api/xml?tree=name,builds[number,result,timestamp,duration]&xpath=freeStyleProject/build[number[. > 100]]&wrapper=builds`

but, this gives the result in XML too.

Is there a way to do the same, but get the result in JSON?

Comment: have you tried `.../api/json?` ..instead of `.../api/xml?` ?

Comment: yes, that returns the result in JSON, but then the XPATH is not applied.

Comment: no, true, there is no (documented) way to achieve this with json. You'd have the opportunity to use the python api (which is most powerful, i think) or process&filter the results through a "json-parser".

Comment: @Sumit Do you know how to get only failed results ?